# How to determine significant subgroups of data inputs?

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a large $(10000 \times 5001)$ table representing $10000$ samples and $5001$ different features of these samples. One of these features represents an output variable of each sample. In other words, I have $5000$ input variables and one output variable for each sample.

I know that most of these inputs are irrelevant. Therefore, what I would like to do is determine the subset of input variables that predicts the output variable best. What is the best/simplest way to go about doing this in R?

Comment: to all reviewers: Please see that the answers in the duplicate question are NOT focused on binary classification, but can be applied to multiclass or regression problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

What people typically do is test the correlation between each feature and the response compute, save and order the p-values and then drop everything but a small percentage with the lowest p-values.  Don't take the p-values seriously.  This was just intended to be a quick screening device.  Once you are down to a small enough number you can go ahead with the standard variable selection techniques used in regression.

Comment: And could you please say what standard variable selection techniques are?